# How can I organize a more engaging Sprint Retrospective?

Tags: scrum, meetings, retrospective

I'm going to be organizing the retro (Scrum) and I would like to get more experience on it. I have assisted to some and have organized some as well, but the format always seems to be

```
| What went wrong            | What worked
          ---                     ---
| What should continue doing | What should we stop doing
```

I will like to do something else or another format, but I'm not knowledgeable enough on the subject to know how to proceed.

**TL;DR:** I will like to get feedback from my team during a the retrospective in a way that it's fun, engaging and productive.

Comment: You can take a look at my Retrospectives Exercises Toolbox at https://www.benlinders.com/exercises/- it provides exercises, ideas, books, and tools to help you defining formats for your retrospectives.

Comment: I would strongly recommend "Agile Retrospectives" by Esther Derby and Diana Larsen.

Comment: great resources from all. Thanks for the help.  I would mark as "correct" @Jo Silverton's anwser cause that's the only one under "Answers" except if anyone has any objections ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of different options for retrospectives depending on what you want to get out of them. The book [Agile Retrospectives](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0977616649) by Diana Larsen and Esther Darby is a great place to look.

I also highly recommend looking at [Retromat](https://retromat.org) for ideas.

As a final piece of advice, I would consider using the 5-stage retrospective talked about in both of those two resources. While it may feel a little over-structured and take a little longer, it ensures that the format of the retro is solidly geared towards valuable outcomes.

Answer (score 1):

The Spotify Squad Health Check model is quite interesting ([here](https://labs.spotify.com/2014/09/16/squad-health-check-model/)), and provides a list of topics that could be used as 'deep dives' if you wanted to vary the content of retrospectives, by focusing on a specific topic every now and then. We've used this to conduct a survey of all our technical staff on our existing projects, to find out areas that we should be concentrating on, and where the most painpoints lie.